# Update positions of others row in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbctemplate

I have multiple `taskDetailIds` against a single `taskId`.

I change status of `taskdetails` on deletion of `taskdetails`. For this operation I just change status from `ACTIVE` to `DELETED`. But as soon as one record is deleted, i.e updated in my case to `DELETE`, I have to update new positions.

Example: If 4th is deleted, new position should be 1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8.
Similarly if 6th is deleted, new positions should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7.

Table schema:
`taskId,taskDetailId,Status,Position`

Comment: Do you need to update the column or just a select statement?

Comment: @forpas i have to update positions new value in column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This counts all the rows containing status = 'ACTIVE' and position less than the current position:

```
update tablename t
inner join (
  select t.*,
    (select count(*) from tablename
    where taskid = 6 and status = 'ACTIVE' and position < t.position) + 1 counter
  from tablename t
) g on g.taskid = t.taskid and g.taskDetailId = t.taskDetailId 
set t.position = g.counter
where t.taskid = 6;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/arLWmSZevGqxZF9sKEXXCA/0).
Results:

```
| taskId | taskDetailId | Status  | Position |
| ------ | ------------ | ------- | -------- |
| 6      | 10           | ACTIVE  | 1        |
| 6      | 11           | ACTIVE  | 2        |
| 6      | 12           | ACTIVE  | 3        |
| 6      | 13           | DELETED | 4        |
| 6      | 14           | ACTIVE  | 4        |
| 6      | 15           | ACTIVE  | 5        |
| 6      | 16           | ACTIVE  | 6        |
| 6      | 17           | ACTIVE  | 7        |
| 6      | 18           | ACTIVE  | 8        |
```

Comment: Why? Did you see the demo?

Comment: `t` is just an alias for the table's name. I used the same alias in more than 1 cases because they are not conflicting with each other. The query counts how many active positions exist before each position.

Comment: This part of the query: `(select count(*) from tablename where taskid = 6 and status = 'ACTIVE' and position < t.position) + 1 ` counts for each position how many ACTIVE positions exist. So for position = 3 there will be 2 (1 and 2) and with adding 1 will be 3 and this value is updated. Maybe (I'm not sure about it) you can change the condition `position < t.position` to `taskDetailId < t.taskDetailId`.

Comment: Then the table is joined to this query by taskId  and taskDetailId  and each position of the table is updated to the calculated counter.

Comment: If you delete position 4, then it will be 1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8 it does not change the deleted position's number. If you delete position 8 it will be: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8 again it does not change the deleted position's number. The same if you delete the last position 9 it will be: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 again it does not change the deleted position's number, just like the requirement in your question. See this: db-fiddle.com/f/arLWmSZevGqxZF9sKEXXCA/1

Comment: *as soon as elements ==totalElems it should remove last position by 1* what do you mean? Give an example.

Comment: Why? In all your examples in the question, the deleted item's position does not change. All the positions after the deleted item are reduced by 1. If the deleted item is the last then nothing changes.

Answer (score -1):

Just calculate the position when you are fetching the data.  In MySQL 8+:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by task_id order by col3) as position
from t
where task_id = 6 and status = 'ACTIVE';
```

Comment: Using version 5.7